# Cancel button does not dismiss ComposeMail window in iOS simulator

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

My implementation is pretty simple:

In the `.h` file, I'm implementing `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate`

And in the `.m` file, I have the following bit of code:

```
-(void)MailCurrentViewAsAttachment
{   
    if ( [MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail] ) {
        MFMailComposeViewController * mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailComposer.delegate = self;
        [mailComposer addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"attachment.jpg"];

        [self presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The variable `imageData` above is of the UIImage type, and I know for sure there's nothing wrong with it: the required image shows up properly in the compose mail window.

However clicking the Cancel button does not dismiss the Compose window. What am I missing?

Note: I'm using iOS 6 with the latest version of xcode, and my app is a Universal app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the wrong delegate. You want:

```
mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
```

`MFMailComposeViewController` extends `UINavigationController`. So setting `delegate` is for the `UINavigationControllerDelegate`.

Comment: Thanks! I just found this out minutes after posting the question. I'll mark your answer in 5 minutes.

Comment: FYI - In the future, if you find the answer to a question before anyone replies, you can delete the question, or feel free to post your own answer.